# Add repeating sequence of numbers to each line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following data:

```
Control_Control_61,GTGGTAGCCACCTGGTGCGC
Control_Control_62,GCCATCTAGGCCTGTGTTGC
Control_Control_63,GCGCCGAGCGTAACAATGTT
Control_Control_64,GATTTGTATGAGCTCAACTC
Control_Control_65,GACGGTGCCACACTTACCAG
Control_Control_66,GGCTATAATACGGTATCGTA
Control_Control_67,GTAATCGAGTCGCCTCTGCA
Control_Control_68,GTTTCTCGCACCACCTCAAG
Control_Control_69,GTGTTCGTACCCGCCACATG
Control_Control_70,GTTTCCCAGTGGGTTTACGA
...
```

After the first instance of `Control` I would like to add a number from 1 to 5 that is repeated throughout the data, in order to get the following:

```
Control1_Control_61,GTGGTAGCCACCTGGTGCGC
Control1_Control_62,GCCATCTAGGCCTGTGTTGC
Control1_Control_63,GCGCCGAGCGTAACAATGTT
Control1_Control_64,GATTTGTATGAGCTCAACTC
Control1_Control_65,GACGGTGCCACACTTACCAG
Control2_Control_66,GGCTATAATACGGTATCGTA
Control2_Control_67,GTAATCGAGTCGCCTCTGCA
Control2_Control_68,GTTTCTCGCACCACCTCAAG
Control2_Control_69,GTGTTCGTACCCGCCACATG
Control2_Control_70,GTTTCCCAGTGGGTTTACGA
```

up to Control5_... then the numbers 1 to 5 are repeated for the remainder of the data

How can I do this with awk/sed or anything else?

Another acceptable outcome would be this:

```
Control1_Control_61,GTGGTAGCCACCTGGTGCGC
Control2_Control_62,GCCATCTAGGCCTGTGTTGC
Control3_Control_63,GCGCCGAGCGTAACAATGTT
Control4_Control_64,GATTTGTATGAGCTCAACTC
Control5_Control_65,GACGGTGCCACACTTACCAG
Control1_Control_66,GGCTATAATACGGTATCGTA
Control2_Control_67,GTAATCGAGTCGCCTCTGCA
Control3_Control_68,GTTTCTCGCACCACCTCAAG
Control4_Control_69,GTGTTCGTACCCGCCACATG
Control5_Control_70,GTTTCCCAGTGGGTTTACGA
...
```

Comment: please update the question with *a)* details on how you determine the numbering in the first data set (assign `1` to 5 rows, assign `2` to 5 rows? some other logic?) and *b)* the code you've tried so far and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: You should provide sample input where the number has to wrap back around to 1 again, otherwise it's not adequate to test with. You could also use 3 instead of 5 to avoid clutter.

Comment: Is the first part of the text **always** literally the word `Control`?

Answer (score 3):

With awk and modular arithmetic on the line number:

first output

```
awk 'sub( /Control/, "&"((int((NR-1)/5)%5)+1) )'
```

second output

```
awk 'sub( /Control/, "&"(((NR-1)%5)+1) )'
```

These assume every line contains at least one instance of "Control" but don't care where.

Comment: In first script, the first `5` ([stride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) / repetitions per value) can be adjusted independently from the second `5` (range of possible values). Both are 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '
  {$1 = sprintf("%s%d", $1, counter+1); print}
  (NR % 5) == 0 {counter = (counter+1) % 5}'
```

If we feed your sample data to that script, we get as output:

```
Control1_Control_61,GTGGTAGCCACCTGGTGCGC
Control1_Control_62,GCCATCTAGGCCTGTGTTGC
Control1_Control_63,GCGCCGAGCGTAACAATGTT
Control1_Control_64,GATTTGTATGAGCTCAACTC
Control1_Control_65,GACGGTGCCACACTTACCAG
Control2_Control_66,GGCTATAATACGGTATCGTA
Control2_Control_67,GTAATCGAGTCGCCTCTGCA
Control2_Control_68,GTTTCTCGCACCACCTCAAG
Control2_Control_69,GTGTTCGTACCCGCCACATG
Control2_Control_70,GTTTCCCAGTGGGTTTACGA
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/1111122222333334444455555/;x}
        /Control/{G;s/(Control)(.*\n)(.)(.*)/\1\3\2\4\3/;P;s/.*\n//;h;d}' file
```

Prep the hold space with the numbers (five 1's, five 2's ...).

If a line contains `Control`, append the hold space and using pattern matching, insert the first number following the newline and then rotate that number to the back.

Print the amended line and then delete it.

Replace the hold space with the rotated version and delete the current line.

Repeat.

---

This can easily be adapted to rotate numbers 1 to 5:

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/12345/;x}
        /Control/{G;s/(Control)(.*\n)(.)(.*)/\1\3\2\4\3/;P;s/.*\n//;h;d}' file
```